# Reading a a ReadableStream and specifying a size param: Why does state.highWaterMark always get passed to ._read() as the size?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node.js, I've got a Readable stream:

```
var rs = new (require('stream').Readable);                                                                                                                                                                                                    
rs._read = function(size) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  // Implementation. 
}
```

This stream gets read in this HTTP server instance:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {                                                                                                                                                                                           
  var size = require('url').parse(req.url, true).query.size;                                                                                                                                                                                  
  if (size) {    
    rs.pipe(res);                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    rs.read(parseInt(size));
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  res.end('');                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
});                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

server.listen(3001, function() {                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  console.log('Listening on 3001');                                                                                                                                                                                                           
});
```

Now, when I `curl localhost:3001/?size=n`, where n is any integer, `size` in `rs._read(size)` is always 16384! This number is the default value of the stream's `state.highWaterMark`, because `rs._read()` is called as `this._read(state.highWaterMark);` in `lib/_stream_readable.js`. Can anyone explain this? What's the point of the `size` param if it's not used?

Thank you.

Comment: No idea what's happening, but 16384 is 0x4000, which looks like some kind of error code.

Comment: Is it wrong to `rs.read(size).pipe(res)`? To me that makes sense, but I'm new to streams.

Comment: @dimadima 16,384 is the byte limit on the combined size of all HTTP request headers. I have no knowledge of streams but it seems to me you're reading the URL query parameter incorrectly.

Comment: Maybe you're seeing some buffering going on? As in, you request 11 bytes, but to improve performance something somewhere attempts to fill a 16kB buffer first and then hand you data from it.

Comment: @JayPatel Interesting, I will think about that!

Comment: @millimoose: Hmm, interesting, but that would _seemingly_ defeat the point of that param, right? I will check out how this behaves w/o the `.pipe()` to `res` and update shortly

Comment: @dimadima Well the documentation states the param is "advisory" whatever that means. Doesn't Node.js come with a debugger that would show you the call stack that you could poke around to see where the `2^14` comes from?

Comment: So `size` has already a wrong value in `rs.read()`, right? Then it shouldn't have something to do with the `pipe` method. I also tested it without pipe, and the output was 11. I used a browser instead of curl though. I don't know maybe I missed something? Maybe you should use quotes in you curl command?

Comment: @TedHopp, [this has nothing to do with error codes](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/0882a7506394e07ae6564ccf3db401b8fb7f7071/lib/_stream_readable.js#L320).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that's just the `highWaterMark` of the stream and [**not coincidentally**](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/0882a7506394e07ae6564ccf3db401b8fb7f7071/lib/_stream_readable.js#L320) the default `size`. [Read more here](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.13/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size_1)

```
var stream = require("stream");

var rs = new stream.Readable();

{ _readableState:
   { highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: false,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     calledRead: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     objectMode: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _maxListeners: 10 }
```

Comment: +1, [that seems to be what happens](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/0882a7506394e07ae6564ccf3db401b8fb7f7071/lib/_stream_readable.js#L320) when `n` is not a number

Comment: Was just stepping through the code and ended up in the same spot. That's actually close to what's going on, but not quite! `._read()` is called with `state.highWaterMark`always. In fact, it's never invoked with any other amount. I need to look at this more to figure out what's going on, but it's pretty weird, considering that `n = howMuchToRead(n, state);` happens just a tad above that, but the new `n` is never used. Gotta look further into this.

Comment: Update my question to reflect these comments. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I wondered about that at first, too. It would be modified at [line 237](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/0882a7506394e07ae6564ccf3db401b8fb7f7071/lib/_stream_readable.js#L237), but you never get that far since [it returns before](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/0882a7506394e07ae6564ccf3db401b8fb7f7071/lib/_stream_readable.js#L221) in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's wrong to call

```
rs.read(size).pipe(res);
```

This is because according to [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size_1), `rs.read(size)` returns a buffer, a string, or `null`. However, `pipe()` is a method of `Readable`. You should probably be using

```
rs.pipe(res);
rs.read(size);
```

Comment: Thanks— this is also totally an issue.